# Plotly in R: Is there any setting so that the legend will not be selected at the beginning？

Tags: r, plotly

How to make the graph not select all the legends when it is generated？ Just like as below.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
p1 <-
    iris%>%
    group_by(Species)%>%
    plot_ly(x=~Sepal.Length, color= ~Species, legendgroup=~Species)%>%
    add_markers(y= ~Sepal.Width)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `visible = 'legendonly'` in `plot_ly` but it shows no legend on load as opposite to only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding each trace (`Species`) separatly to the plot, you can manually set the visibility of each trace.

```
# divide dataset by group
iris_sub <- iris %>% 
  group_split(Species)

# create base for plot
p <- plotly::plot_ly(type="scatter",
                     mode="markers")

# add a trace for each group
lapply(iris_sub, function(f) {
  
  # define visible group (just show virginica)
  vis <- ifelse(unique(f[, "Species"]) == "virginica", TRUE, "legendonly")
  
  # add trace to plot
  p <<- get("p") %>% 
    add_trace(p, data = f, 
              x = ~Sepal.Length,
              y = ~Sepal.Width,
              color = ~Species,
              visible = vis)  
})
```

[image]